# Two data should output unique values in csv using python

Tags: python

I'm a new python student and having issues in my csv output, it has duplicates of the matched condition I've searched it all over the internet already and found none.

How do i make this output, any method will do fine.

```
Data 1:
sitename,
www.google.com,
www.facebook.com,
www.twitter.com,
www.amazon.com

Data 2
sitename, founding date
www.google.com, 09/14/1998
www.amazon.com, 07/05/1994

if data 1 == data2['founding date']:
    writer.writerow([Data1, Founding Date])
else:
    writer.writerow([Data1, ''])
```

the Output should be:

```
sitename, Founding date
www.google.com, 09/14/1998
www.facebook.com,
www.twitter.com,
www.amazon.com, 07/05/1994
```

My Output:

```
sitename, Founding date,
www.google.com
www.google.com, 09/14/1998
www.facebook.com,
www.twitter.com,
www.amazon.com
www.amazon.com, 07/05/1994
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please be more specific in your inputs - are those two CSV files? Are they in a data structure? My guess is that you are looping through both data lists, so it is outputting the results for all 6 lines, but more detail would be helpful.

Comment: Sorry this is my first time asking here, they are yaml file and yes they are looping I get the value (like www.google.com, www.facebook.com etc.) through a list in yaml file by enumerating its name sitename which contains the sitename key and its list like ['www.googl.com, etc..'] and i am supposed to matched it in another yaml file name which i enumerate too named sitename_details with the founding date which should output all the sitenames to matched with the founding date if there is no founding date it should just be blank. thanks a lot!.

Answer (score 0):

Trying out pandas...

```
import pandas as pd
import io

Data1 = '''\
sitename,
www.google.com,
www.facebook.com,
www.twitter.com,
www.amazon.com
'''

Data2 = '''\
sitename, founding date
www.google.com, 09/14/1998
www.amazon.com, 07/05/1994
'''

d1 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(Data1), skipinitialspace=True)
d2 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(Data2), skipinitialspace=True, parse_dates=[1])

d3 = pd.merge(d1, d2, on='sitename', how='left')

print(d3[['sitename', 'founding date']])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
data1 = '''
sitename,
www.google.com,
www.facebook.com,
www.twitter.com,
www.amazon.com
'''

data2 = '''
sitename, founding date
www.google.com, 09/14/1998
www.amazon.com, 07/05/1994
'''

data1_rows = list(filter(str, data1.split("\n")))
data2_dict = {i.split(',')[0].strip(): i.split(',')[1] for i in list(filter(str, data2.split("\n"))) if i.count(",") > 0}
for i in data1_rows:
    val = i.strip(",")
    if val in data2_dict:
        writer.writerow([val, data2_dict[val]])
    else:
        writer.writerow([i])
```

This solution is parsing the data2 to dict and then iterate over data1 lines and checking if the value in data1 row has a key in the data2_dict if so it writes to the file the data1 line value with the respective line for data2 else only data1 row value.